# Date in Grails criteria does not return any records

Tags: grails

I am using grails criteria to retrieve some records from oracle db. Like below,

```
def a = DomainClass.createCriteria()
def recordList=a.list{
    'lt'("modifiedDate", myDate)
}
```

But it does not return any records, when I run the query as a sql the same myDate works when I pass it under oracle to_date function.

myDate is a java.util.date. I tried formatting it using SimpleTextFormat and converting back to groovy Date  using new Date().

But same result

Comment: `'lt'` should not be in quotes

Comment: was that the reason here ? as the same criteria works when I pass some other parameter like a Long value

Comment: Did you try with dynamic finders ? DomainClass.findAllByModifiedDateLessThan(myDate)

Comment: Yes tried that but same result only. Is there any problem with using dates in criteria always ?

Comment: No, I have no problem with Date. Is myDate a Date ? And it's probably not the problem, but there is a typo in your question, it is DomainClass.createCriteria() (you forgot the last r).

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I corrected my question. In my case at first I tried myDate as java.util.date, then I formatted it using SimpleDateFormat and then did a parse with new Date(), but still I am getting the same result. But when I pass myDate into a sql inside a to_date function, it works fine :(

Comment: That's really strange because I have no problem with criteria and Date (grails 2.3.7 and postgresql or mysql). Did you try to use 'java.sql.Date' instead of 'java.util.Date' for your domain ? 
Do you have result with the this one: DomainClass.findAllByModifiedDateLessThan(new Date()) ?